# Vandeseer's Easytable - Multiline cells in row

Tags: java, pdfbox

I need to generate a printout that has two cells aligned above each other in a single row as shown in the image below. I am used Vandeseer's Easytable and PDFBox but cannot find any examples of how to do this. Is it possible?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible:

```
// Build the table
Table myTable = Table.builder()
        .addColumnsOfWidth(200, 100, 80, 70)
        .borderColor(Color.GRAY)
        .borderWidth(0.3f)
        .horizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)
        .verticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
        .addRow(Row.builder()
                .add(TextCell.builder().text("Tracking Usage Module").rowSpan(2).build())
                .add(TextCell.builder().text("Start : 09:45").fontSize(8).build())
                .add(TextCell.builder().text("00:40").rowSpan(2).build())
                .add(TextCell.builder().text("€30.00").rowSpan(2).build())
                .build())
        .addRow(Row.builder()
                .add(TextCell.builder().text("End : 10:25").fontSize(8).build())
                .build())
        .build();
```

That would render to:

[image: rendered image]

For the code to render a table in general just see easytable's [minimum working example](https://github.com/vandeseer/easytable/blob/master/src/test/java/org/vandeseer/MinimumWorkingExample.java).